# How do I loop thorough a 2D ArrayList in Java and fill it?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am trying to use 2D arrayLists in Java. 
I have the definition:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> myList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

How can I loop through it and enter in numbers starting from 1? 
I know that I can access a specific index by using:

```
myList.get(i).get(j)
```

Which will get the value. But how do I add to the Matrix?

Thanks

Comment: Well, do you know how to add items to a list? Have you checked the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html)? The [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/TOC.html)?

Comment: Please clarify: Has your structure been initialized? With the definition you list, it is a 0x0 matrix.

Comment: do you know the size of each inner list?

Comment: Yes i know how to add Items to a list.
It has been defined as i wrote it above.
Lets say i want to add 5 rows and 5 cols

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a nested for loop. The i-loop loops through the outer ArrayList and the j-loop loops through each individual ArrayList contained by `myList`

```
for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < myList.get(i).size(); j++)
    {
        // do stuff
    } 
}
```

**Edit:** you then fill it by replacing `// do stuff` with

```
myList.get(i).add(new Integer(YOUR_VALUE)); // append YOUR_VALUE to end of list
```

**A Note:** If the myList is initially unfilled, looping using `.size()` **will not work** as you cannot use `.get(SOME_INDEX)` on an `ArrayList` containing no indices. You will need to loop from 0 to the number of values you wish to add, create a new list within the first loop, use `.add(YOUR_VALUE)` to append a new value on each iteration to this new list and then add this new list to `myList`. See [Ken's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33509771/5087118) for a perfect example.

Comment: This won't work if myList is empty. If you could get to the inner loop somehow, you'd get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` before you could even add anything.

Comment: Just saw. Lemme check what says.

Comment: It wont let me write the 
`myList.get(i).get(j).add(new Integer(YOUR_VALUE));`
it gives an error when writing the add

Comment: It shouldn't work. You can't `get()` from an empty list.

Comment: @Monkeygrinder I know. I'll re-edit to make that clearer though.

Comment: @bpgeck I know. The initial question was a bit awkward. There's still a small correction you have to make though... should be `myList.get(i).add(integer)`. `myList.get(i).get(j)` would get you the Integer at that index, to which using `add()` won't work

Comment: @Monkeygrinder haha you're absolutely correct. Thank you for catching all my errors.

Comment: No problem. It's hard to keep track of all the methods being called some times, let alone know offhand whether it will/won't work. I just have the advantage of having Eclipse open and not being the one writing an actual answer. :p

Answer (score 7):

Use [for-each](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) loop, if you are using Java prior 1.5 version.

```
for(ArrayList<Integer> row : myList) {

  for(Integer intValue : row) {

     // access "row" for inside arraylist or "intValue" for integer value.

  }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the matrix is not initialized,

```
int m = 10, n = 10;
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> matrix = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    List<Integer> row = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        row.add(j);
    }
    matrix.add(row);
}
```

Comment: how to get number of arrays in 2d array list?

Comment: @sameerjoshi, in this problem, it is an array length m of arrays. So there are m+1 arrays.